# userprofile path returns Default while running as a schedule task

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, console-application, special-folders

I have created following C# console app:

```
var userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var path2 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%");

File.AppendAllText(@"D:\logs\info.txt", userName + " -- " + path + " -- " + path2);
```

When I create a scheduled task using Windows Task Scheduler and set the user account to run the task to my account (`ht-laptop\huseyin`), I am getting the following output in **info.txt** file:

```
ht-laptop\huseyin -- C:\Users\Default\Documents -- C:\Users\Default
```

This seems to be random though, I had seen cases where the printed text was as follows:

```
ht-laptop\huseyin -- C:\Users\huseyin\Documents -- C:\Users\huseyin
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Use `Debugger.Break()` to pause the process. Then inspect how it was started with say Process Explorer. Perhaps you have a duplicate task item still setup.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running this on Windows 8+ (or similar)? If so, this is a known issue with user profile loading. The technote ([kb2968540](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2968540)) has a workaround (which is kind of kludgy IMO).

Comment: Yep, I am on Windows 8.1, looks like this is the issue I am having, I am going to try the work around and get you back. Thanks bunch!